# GCM in iphone app using swift

Tags: iphone, google-cloud-messaging, xcode7-beta4

[image]

I am developing an iPhone app using Xcode 7 beta 4 in Swift 2.0

I am trying to implement GCM push notifications following the google doc [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?configured=true&ver=swift)

I have followed and completed the steps upto 
"**Add the configuration file to your project**".
Now when I am trying to add "#**import < Google/CloudMessaging.h >**" in the file.
I am getting error. 
The error is `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'` I think the import statement is not working.
Can some one please tell me how I can do it in the correct way?

Comment: The error is "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' "

I think the import statement is not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the import lines as well as the lines where the error occurs

Comment: This is probably some spacing issue, please post your code and the line with errors

Comment: @ztan I have add a screen shot of the code where I am trying to use the GCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>`" needs to be in your bridging header (which is a .h file), not in your .swift file.

You do have a bridging header file, don't you?

Comment: Do I need to edit the current bridging header file or I will have to create new bridging header file. I am very new to the platfrom. I do not understand much. It will be very kind of you if you can forward me a good tutorial of GCM using xcode7 in swift. Thanks

Comment: remove the #import from the .swift file, add it to the current bridging header file, and let's see if it compiles.  :-)

Comment: It is compiling I was adding the import in the wrong place. Now if I write rest of the code for notification I suppose it will work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad I was able to assist!